# Running an applet without Java

Tags: applet, java

Is there a way to run an applet in a browser without `JRE` or `JDK` on the machine?
If not, is there a way to run an applet in a browser with a light plugin?

Comment: That's simple! Make a JavaScript program that reads bytecode out of a jar, and that emulates a JVM, complete with the standard library. But don't expect to do I/O, though... And it might be (much) slower and bigger than an installed JRE... Not to mention the sheer complexity of this kind of project!

Comment: Note that my tongue-in-cheek proposal isn't as stupid as it seems, if you restrict the scope of the applet: after all, Processing (from Processing.org) made applets but somebody managed to interpret this simplified Java code in JavaScript, making ProcessingJS. Of course, this is an interpreter of a subset of Java, not a full JRE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no solution : an applet needs a JVM to run.

When you [install a Java Plugin](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-141438.html) in your browser, it installs a JRE.

Comment: Your means: install a Java Plugin in browser install a full `JRE` (about 100 MB) on machin?

Comment: Yes. There is no light java solution.

Comment: jre is not 100 MB in size. max 50 MB.

Comment: @SreenathSoman It varies in size. Here on a Windows Computer I have a 107 MB JRE.

Comment: sorry, i was not talking about unpacked size :D

Answer (score 0):

You could run the applet on another machine (perhaps a virtual machine in the other common sense), and then use a remote desktop. The is similar to the way Opera for mobiles works.